# How can I calculate the angle a game character would rotate, from point 1 to 2?

Tags: c#

I'm doing an assignment for a C# Game Development class on Coursera. And one of the assignments is to calculate the distance between two points and an angle a game character would need to rotate to go from the first point to the second.

I'm having trouble calculating the rotation the character would take to get to each of the points and I don't know **how**to use the numbers I get to form an equation to solve for rotation.

But like I've said, I **did** manage to generate a couple numbers *in general*.

This is the work I have so far...

```
using System;

namespace ProgrammingAssignment2
{
    // IMPORTANT: Only add code in the section
    // indicated below. The code I've provided
    // makes your solution work with the 
    // automated grader on Coursera

    /// <summary>
    /// Programming Assignment 2
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        // x and y coordinates for points
        static float point1X;
        static float point1Y;
        static float point2X;
        static float point2Y;

        /// <summary>
        /// Programming Assignment 2
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">command-line args</param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // loop while there's more input
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            while (input[0] != 'q')
            {
                // extract point coordinates from string
                GetInputValuesFromString(input);

                // Add your code between this comment
                // and the comment below. You can of
                // course add more space between the
                // comments as needed

                int point1X = 5;
                int point2X = 4;

                int deltaX = -1;
                int deltaY = -1;

                int point1Y = 5;
                int point2Y = 4;

                int angle2 = -135;

                float hypotnuse = (deltaX * 2 + deltaY * 2);

                float distance = (float)Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(point2X - point1X, 2) + Math.Pow(point2Y - point1X, 2)));

                float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(point2X - point1X, point2Y - point1Y);

                float CumulationofDistanceandHyp = ((distance * 2 + hypotnuse * 2));

                Console.Write( distance + " and " + angle);

                Console.Write("The distance between delta Y and X is  " + hypotnuse);

                Console.Write("Then what is " + CumulationofDistanceandHyp);

                // Don't add or modify any code below
                // this comment
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extracts point coordinates from the given input string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">input string</param>
        static void GetInputValuesFromString(string input)
        {
            // extract point 1 x
            int spaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
            point1X = float.Parse(input.Substring(0, spaceIndex));

            // move along string and extract point 1 y
            input = input.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
            spaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
            point1Y = float.Parse(input.Substring(0, spaceIndex));

            // move along string and extract point 2 x
            input = input.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
            spaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
            point2X = float.Parse(input.Substring(0, spaceIndex));

            // point 2 y is the rest of the string
            input = input.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
            point2Y = float.Parse(input);

            #region Unfortunately, Mono doesn't have a Split method!
            //string[] values = input.Split(' ');
            //point1X = float.Parse(values[0]);
            //point1Y = float.Parse(values[1]);
            //point2X = float.Parse(values[2]);
            //point2Y = float.Parse(values[3]);
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the definition is not enough. Why the character need to rotate?
And If "rotate" means changing orientation, the "initial orientation" data should be needed. How it defined?

Comment: Is this just a cartesian to polar coordinate calculation?

Comment: You have to define for us what each variable represents. For example, what is `deltaX` and `deltaY` and why are they given and not calculated? Also what is `angle2` and why isn't there an `angle1` given also?

Comment: Can you link the assignment? Currently, there isn't enough information in the post to effectively answer.